# Appropriate listener for Swing JTree

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a `JTree`, and based on the selection I want a button to be enabled, so I have used the `TreeSelectionListener` for this :

```
tree.addTeeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event)
    {
        okButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

});
```

The button is getting enabled a bit late by a second or two. What is the problem here?

Am I using the correct listener?

Comment: The button is getting enabled a bit late by a second or two. What is the problem here? == somewhere in rest of your code, for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTRE, short runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local varaibles for SWing JComponent(s)

Comment: It'll be waiting for the EDT. You'll need to handle the call using an `invokeLater`.